# in code invocation of button_Click behaves differently than actually clicking

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, eventhandler

i'm writing a program in c# winforms and there is a `TextBox` that is bound to an entity framework object:

```
BindingList<Settings> bindingList = BillContext.Settings.Local.ToBindingList();
field6TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingList, "CustomerField6");
```

i've created a save button to save the changes into database:

```
private void saveCustomerFields_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    BillContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

everything works fine if i click on the save button, but if i use the key shortcuts that i've created for the save button:

```
private void field6TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    if(e.KeyData.Equals(Keys.Enter))
        saveCustomerFields_Click(sender, e);
}
```

and

```
private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    if(e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S)){
        saveCustomerFields_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

although the save click event handler is called, but the `BillContext.Settings.Local` doesn't change and it results in the changes not being saved into the database.

how does clicking and in code invocation of the button click event handle have different consequences(considering i don't use the method inputs)? and how can i make my key shortcuts work?

Comment: In short, it shouldn't. What does `SaveChanges` do?

Comment: `BillContext` is my class that extends entity frameworks `DbContext`. it Saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace

```
saveCustomerFields_Click(sender, e);
```

with

```
saveCustomerFields.PerformClick();
```

Comment: Your problem is Click event use the parameters (sender and e) from the KeyDown event. BTW, please mark this correct if it help :)